# How are the beans retrieved in Spring-MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In a simple spring application you register your bean in the spring IoC container by using `@Component` annotation and then to retrieve the bean you first read the spring configuration file and then retrieve the bean from container using:

```
ClassPathXMLApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXMLApplicationContext("spring config file")


Coach theCoach=context.getBean("beanId","classname")
```

Now, you can call the methods on `theCoach`.

How are we retrieving the bean from the container as we are not using

```
context.getBean();
```

Is the `DispatcherServlet` handling this?

After editing-

/*********************Spring Application*******************************/
applicationContext.xml

```
<beans _______>

<context:component-scan base-package="packageName"/>

</beans>
```

Coach.java

```
public interface Coach{

public String getDailyWorkOut();

}
```

TennisCoach.java

```
@Component                                                                                                   

public class TennisCoach implements Coach{

public String getDailyWorkOut(){

return "practise back hand volley"; 

}
```

ApplicationDemo.java

```
public class ApplicationDemo{

public static void main(String[] args){

ClassPathXMLApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXMLApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

Coach theCoach=context.getBean("tennisCoach",Coach.class)

theCoach.getDailyWorkOut();

}

}
```

/*********************Spring Application*******************************/

Now for Spring MVC-

```
/*****************Spring-MVC Application**************************/
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
<init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigurationLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans _______>

<context:component-scan base-package="packageName"/>

</beans>
```

Coach.java

```
public interface Coach{

public String getDailyWorkOut();

}
```

TennisCoach.java

```
@Component                                                                                                   

public class TennisCoach implements Coach{

@RequestMapping("/")
public String getDailyWorkOut(){

return "practise back hand volley"; 

}
/*********************Spring-MVC Application*********************/
```

What I want to know is -

That in above given spring application I am retrieving bean from the container using context.getBean(), how is the Coach bean being retrieved in Spring-MVC application?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand clearly your question. Could you rephrase it? Do you want to know how does the framework retrieve beans when needed, for example in an MVC application? Could you use an example to state your point?

Comment: maybe your missing concept is injection: with \@Autowired or \@Inject, you are telling the framework to put there an existing object retrieved from the context that match the declared type.

Comment: @lealcelderio Yes ,yes that'w what I want to know. How does the Spring-MVC framework retrieve beans when needed. JUST want to know where is context.getBean() implemented in Spring-MVC as we are not writing it explicitly?

Comment: @spi mentioned the key aspects for your answer. More detailed information may be internal implementation of the MVC framework. You could read about what is mentioned by spi and then if you have a more specific question come back here and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56072627/edit) the post.

Comment: @lealceldeiro Appreciate your suggestion ,I have an idea about how \@Autowired works or how it injects dependencies. I have edited my question and included an example.I hope my query is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just create field with annotation @Autowired and spring inject it for you. Make sure your class where you are going to use this bean is also spring bean.

Answer (score 0):

In you example you are retrieving bean via **bean lookup** from `ApplicationContext`.

```java
Coach theCoach=context.getBean("tennisCoach",Coach.class)
```

In this case you know exact class name you need(such you are an author of your bean), and you simply get it from the context.

---

For `DispatcherServlet` it is not so easy, because it knows nothing about beans you've added to the context.

The only option it has is a full scanning of all defined in the context beans and detecting anything it can recognise (`Controller`, `RestController`, `RequestMapping`). Example of such *detector* is [AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.html) with it's implementations. SpringMvc has various implementations of such detectors, you can implement your own if you need.